# How to get specific column key from data frame given a particular element?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider the data frame

```
   c1   c2   c3  
0 a 3    4    2  
1 b 1    2    7
```

say I want to know which column in row 1 has the element 7. how will I achieve it?
I am trying to achieve it using pandas.

Comment: I would recommend reading the thread posted below, it will make a big difference on how people help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want get column of first value in row with index `1`:

```
a = df.loc[1].eq(7).idxmax()
print (a)
c3
```

Explanation:

First select column with index by `loc`:

```
print (df.loc[1])
c1    4
c2    2
c3    7
Name: (1, b), dtype: int64
```

Compare with `7`:

```
print (df.loc[1].eq(7))
c1    False
c2    False
c3     True
Name: (1, b), dtype: bool
```

and for `c3` get index of max value, it means first `True`.

If row contains multiple values (here 7) and need all matched columns use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
a = df.loc[1].eq(7)
a = a.index[a].tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what output you're looking for, but I believe this will help. I started by creating your dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1':['3', '1'],
                   'c2':['4', '2'],
                   'c3':['2', '7']})
```

The following code reads like so: give me all the records where the column 'c3' equals 7.

```
df = df[df['c3'] == '7']
```

Output:

[image]